# Using `repomirror` to mirror a yum repository for a different OS version?

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm, scientific-linux

I have an EL5 machine. On this host I would like to mirror a Puppet repository for EL6 rpms. How can I mirror an EL6 or Fedora repository on an EL5 host?

I am using `reposync` because I only need the newest packages available on the repo, not the entire repository.

My .repo file contains this:

```
# cat puppetlabs.repo.el6
[main]
# Override default releasever, per `man yum.conf`
releasever=6
# Try distroverpkg instead?
distroverpkg=6

[puppetlabs-products]
name=Puppet Labs Products El 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=0=1
gpgcheck=1
```

My command line is as follows. As you can see, `reposync` is affixing 'el5' to the URL when I need it to say 'el6'.

```
# lsb_release -r
Release:        5.10
# reposync --newest-only --repoid=puppetlabs-products --config=puppetlabs.repo.el6 --urls
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/facter-1.6.6-1.el5.noarch.rpm
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/facter-2.0.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/hiera-1.3.2-1.el5.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @devicenull for leading me down the right path. I got the following to work. I had to hardcode `distroverpkg` as well as the `cachedir` and `persistdir`.

Here is my repo file:

```
# cat puppetlabs.repo.el6

# NOTE: This [main] section is required to workaround yum wierdness when we mirror distroverpkg=6 from an el5 host
[main]
distroverpkg=6
cachedir=/var/cache/puppetlabsmirror.el6/cache/
persistdir=/var/cache/puppetlabsmirror.el6/var
keepcache=0

[puppetlabs-products]
name=Puppet Labs Products El 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

And now the following command works fine:

```
# reposync --config=puppetlabs.repo.el6 --repoid=puppetlabs-products --newest-only --urls    http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/facter-1.6.7-1.el6.noarch.rpm
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/facter-2.0.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/hiera-1.3.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks, `distroverpkg` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the machine you're using also has the puppetlabs repo installed in /etc/yum.repos.d/?  If you remove it from there (and flush the yum cache), do you still see this issue?

I would suspect you're going to want to give reposync an entirely new yum.conf (via --config), specifying a different cache directory then the normal system one.

Comment: I removed the pre-existing puppetlabs repo from `/etc/yum.repos.d/` but I did not flush the yum cache. I'll try that. I did try `--config` but I did not try a separate cache.

Comment: I did `yum clean all` and hardcoded `cachedir=/tmp/test/cache/` to the `[main]` section of my conf file. It still doesn't work.